# ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory is unable to one-hot encode data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am using `ImageDataGenerator` (tensorflow version 2.5.0) to load in a number of jpg files that I am using for a classification system. I have specified the `class_mode='categorical'`. My images are originally RGB, but even though I am converting them to greyscale I don't think that should matter. However, when I call `train_set.classes`, the data I get is not one-hot encoded data, but it is sparse numerical data. Here is my `ImageDataGenerator` call:

```
def preprocessing_function(image):
    neg = 1 - image
    return neg

#image_path = sys.argv[1]
image_path = ''

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    vertical_flip=True,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    preprocessing_function=preprocessing_function)

train_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    os.path.join(image_path, 'endo_jpg/endo_256_2021_08_05/Training'),
    target_size=(100,100),
    batch_size=batch,
    class_mode='categorical',
    color_mode='grayscale')
```

Upon calling the `flow_from_directory` method, I am returned what I expect:

> Found 625 images belonging to 4 classes.

Calling `train_set.classes`, I am returned a long list of integers, not one hot encoded data:

> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
> 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
> 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
> 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3])

I can force the data to be one hot encoded by using:
`train_set.classes = tensorflow.keras.utils.to_categorical(train_set.classes)`, but then I can't train with the data generator.

I think there is a problem with my specifying `class_mode='categorical'`, but I have no idea why. I followed the example in the documentation ([here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_directory)), but calling categorical returns a sparse label.

Comment: why is that a problem? you don't specify a target in `model.fit()` you just give the generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply calling `train_set[0]` clearly shows me the images and the labels. The printed labels are one hot encoded based on my code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `class_mode='categorical'` you don't have to manually convert the labels to one hot encoded vectors using `to_categorical()`.

The Generator will return labels as categorical automatically.

Comment: The Generator is returning my labels as sparse labels, but I want it to return one hot encoded labels. That is my entire issue

Comment: @DanielSherman it's `train_set.classes` which returns your labels as integers. But when the generator is used with `model.fit()` the labels are being automatically one hot encoded